# Configuring proxy on the Blackberry Playbook simulator

Tags: tablet, blackberry

Has anyone had any success configuring the proxy on the Blackberry Playbook simulator? We are behind a proxy (that requires authentication), and none of the apps can access the internet as of now. Any ideas?